# How to install Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition on trial?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to install SQL Server 2014 `Standard` and `Enterprise` editions on two separated servers with same hardware in order to test the performances differences running internal set of procedures.

The DBA gave me two `ISO`s with the following name:

```
SW_DVD9_SQL_Svr_Standard_Edtn_2014w_SP1_64Bit_English_-2_MLF_X20-29010
SW_DVD9_SQL_Svr_Ent_Core_2014w_SP1_64Bit_English_-2_MLF_X20-28988
```

claiming they are downloaded from Microsoft , but once I have installed them and run:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

I get the following for the `Enterprise` edition:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64)     Jun  9 2015 12:06:16 
>     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Evaluation Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

and the following for the `Standard` edition:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64)     Jun  9 2015 12:06:16 
>     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Evaluation Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

So, what I am doing wrong? Why, when I am using the `Standard` iso again `Enterprise` is istanlled?

---

I guess this should be SP1 issue, because I have checked that I had successfully install standard edition of SQL Server 2014 without SP1.

Comment: Looks like you chose evaluation edition during setup. Afaik the ISOs are identical; which edition gets installed depends on the license key you enter during install, unless you pick free (express / eval). Also there's no way to create an evaluation standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Evaluation Edition is always Enterprise Edition. If you want to run comparisons, get your admins to give you Standard Edition rather than Evaluation Edition.

For more proof, check Books Online, which notes that there is an Enterprise Evaluation, but not a Standard:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx